# fetching multiple row in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a little project, but unfortunately, my hosting does not support the package mysqldn, therefore I am unable to work with `fetch_all()` function. This is the block of code thats causing headaches to me.

```
public function fetch($type = 'object')
{
    if (isset($this->result))
    {
        switch ($type)
        {
            case 'array':

                //fetch a row as array
                //$row = $this->result->fetch_all();
                $rows = array();
                while($row = $this->result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
            break;

            case 'object':

            //fall through...

            default:

                //fetch a row as object
                $row = $this->result->fetch_object();   

            break;
        }

        return $rows;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

As I said previously, I can not use `fetch_all()` function on my current hosting. Therefore, is there any alternative to that function? what can I do?

Comment: What kind of headaches? Doesn't ii do the very job it's intended for?

Comment: a more concise way to say it is `while($rows[] = $this->result->fetch_assoc()){}`

Comment: @Orangepill this is a wrong way actually

Comment: After a little research I found that this my method is broken. Best case with a `mysqli_result` it yields an array of the row arrays but it also puts null as the last element. Looking at the code now it's obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native mysqli->fetch() function will return the next row in the resultset until it reaches the end.

Just call it once if you just want to get the next row, or you can include it in a loop if you want to get all rows, for example

```
while($row = $this->result->fetch())
{
    //Do something with $row
}
```

**Edit:** This relates to fetching results for prepared statements only, and would only work where $this->result held the result of store_result() after execution of a prepared statement.

Comment: that is what the OP is trying to avoid having to do

Comment: I wonder why this answer was upvoted and accepted. As a matter of fact, this code will never work as intended.